# mod_rewrite over mod_alias / Ordering and precedence

Tags: mod-rewrite, mod-alias

Within a multi-server shared hosting I am using this

```
RedirectMatch temp "/.well-known/acme-challenge/(.*)" "https://FOO.BAR.TLD/$1"
```

to redirect all Let's Encrypt requests to one server.

The problem: If someone (customer ;-) ) is using e.g.

```
RedirectPermanent / http://somewhereelse
```

the RedirectPermanent takes precedence over RedirectMatch (which is logical).

So I replaced my central rule with

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule "^/.well-known/acme-challenge/(.*)" "https://FOO.BAR.TLD/$1" [L,R=302]
```

but even with the "L"-Flag, mod_alias (RedirectPermanent) is getting executed.

Does anyone see any chance to "fix" this so that my central rule is getting executed at any time?

BTW: I also tried to ensure that "my" rule is the last one (and the first one) in apache config by ordering file names, but the RedirectPermanent of the customer alwa

Comment: The order in which Apache handles various Directives is a very complicated, case-by-case determination based on not only the placement of Directives in your configuration file, but on the handling order specified by the relevant modules as well as the [Apache merging rules](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/sections.html#merging).

Comment: "If someone (customer ;-) ) is using..." - are you referring to the "customers" use of `.htaccess` here? In what _context_ (Server, VirtualHost or Directory) are you placing this directive in the server config?

Comment: I am using "my" global configuration in Server context, but even when placing in VirtualHost or Directory, the "RedirectPermanent" done by the customer always takes priority over everything.